# How can I use a matrix element to plot with ParametricPlot?

Tags: plotting, matrix

*This is a completely simplified example to demonstrate the issue.*

I have a matrix, it contains an uninitialized variable. I need to extract that element of the matrix and use in to plot a parametric function of that variable.

```
m = t; // this is the matrix 1x1, inserted via the graphical context menu;
ParametricPlot[{Part[m, 1], 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

I get an empty plot.

---

Strangely, it works with the plain plot, I checked it, but I need the parametric one:

```
Plot[{Part[m, 1]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Could anyone suggest something, please?

---

I need this to perform certain transformations on "vectors", which contain variables, in order to plot this. I can go without it, currently I'm simply doing:

```
Print[Part[m, 1]];
```

then manually copy-pasting the output of Print into ParametricPlot:

```
ParametricPlot[{t * Cos[Pi], 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

and get what I want. The problem is that I have many more values, than in this example. I thought, that it might be that someone could suggest something.

Comment: This is not Matlab. As defined, `m` is a scalar. (And your second example suffers from the same problem btw.) Only `m = {{t}}` defines a matrix; `m = {t}` defines a vector. The latter is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I inserted the matrix via the graphical interface with the context menu's "insert matrix", so it's definitely a matrix. It's just that in my Mathematica notebook it looks like this (without any parenthesis). The second example works, I double checked.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fortunately, your problem is already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I define `m` in the manner you describe, I get

[image: m]

And, yes, that's definitely a 1 x 1 matrix, which means its first (and only) element is referred by `m[[1,1]]` (or `Part[m,1,1]`). So to make a parametric plot, I write

```
ParametricPlot[{m[[1, 1]], 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

and get

[image: plot]

Does this solve your problem?

Note: Anything in Mathematica that qualifies as a matrix will be composed of elements that require ***two*** indices to reference them.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need. Using `m[[1,1]]` instead of `Part[m, 1]` is the solution for some reason

Comment: `require two indices to reference them` that was the problem. Part works with one index for simple lists, but not matrices

Comment: Or `Part[m, 1, 1]`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi. Already said that in the answer